# How to show the same ImageView multiple times programmatically?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to make a simple "game" were a circle moves up, down, left or right in some Grids (Not clickable, just an `ImageView`). I want to add multiple of the same Image with only one ImageView

I have have tried to find the simplest way possible as shown here:

```
Integer img = R.drawable.trans_grid_2;
ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
iView.setImageResource(img);

constraintLayout.addView(iView);
constraintLayout.addView(iView); //Cannot add 2 or more of the same Image
```

This gives me a error *(Crashes app at startup)*:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

It indicates that I have to call removeView() before re-using it. But, I want to add multiple of the same Images without something complicated in java. I cant add the same ImageView more than twice

I have tried googling this, but it shows me some complicated-ish ways and not what I need.

How can I add 2 or more of the same ImageView in java?

Comment: "How can I add 2 or more of the same ImageView in java?" – You can't. Why is creating multiple `ImageView`s a problem?

Comment: Beacuse I cant just make 20 Images Views for the same exact Image. Is there really _no_ way of re-adding the Image multiple times?

Comment: "Beacuse I cant just make 20 Images Views for the same exact Image." – Sure you can. I'm not saying it's necessarily the best solution, as I'm not really sure what you're doing, but you most certainly can make multiple `ImageView`s for the same image.

Comment: I was wondering If i could use one ImageView and add multiple of them. Guess not, I think ill just do an array of images.(Or other solutions, down below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Integer img = R.drawable.trans_grid_2;
int NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_IMAGES; i++) {
    ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
    iView.setImageResource(img);

    constraintLayout.addView(iView);
}
```

You can add instance of a view only to one parent.

Comment: This type of scenario fits well, and will allow me to position grids without  using many images. THanks!